# Google-api search in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-api, fetch

I did get a google costumsearch api correctly with 200 ok but I didn't get the information correctly in my app my code looks like this I want to get items but it returns undedfined

```
fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={key}&cx={cx}&q=" +
        this.state.query
    ).then(response => {
      this.setState({ results: response.items });
      console.log(response.items);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `fetch` doesn't return the response body, it returns a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response) object. To get the response body as json, you can use the method `json`, which return a new promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON:

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={key}&cx={cx}&q=" + this.state.query)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({ results: response.items });
        console.log(response.items);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `response.json().then(() => {})`